# install java or just copy jdk file?

Tags: java, windows, java-11, javaw

I am working on a windows 10 virtual machine which I want to run on it java application.
when I tried to run it I get an error "Windows cannot find 'javaw'" since java is not installed.
Now if I want to have java on the machine, should I install java ? or I can only copy paste the java jdk that I already have on my workstation?
On my workstation I have java jdk 11 folder which has the below files/folders:

- bin
- conf
- include
- jmods
- legal
- lib

Note: I don't have access to internet from my windows 10 VM

Comment: Asking for trouble to do anything other than install it really. Get the offline installer

Comment: Just copying the _jdk 11 folder_ should be enough. Make sure that you update the PATH environment variable to include the path to the folder containing file `javaw.exe`

Comment: @Abra where would the registry entries come from?

Comment: @g00se what [Windows] registry keys are you referring to? According to [this](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0604.html) none are required. That's why I wrote that the PATH environment variable needs to be updated.

Comment: Well it normally reads registry keys to do most everything ;) You might get away with it in this case maybe but copying stuff is really just error-prone in general

Comment: You don't need to run any installer or add registry keys to have JDK on Windows, you can copy all the folders from compatible JDK (or from jlink if want JRE) or extract any of the supplied ZIP files for the platform. But you do need to take care about how you set up PATH to know which one is used, or add say Windows Terminal profiles to setup command prompts for each versions.

Comment: @g00se every download site (e.g. [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows) or [adoptium](https://adoptium.net/de/temurin/releases/?version=19) offers to download zip files you can just extract to some location. Messing around with the registry precisely is a reason for me not to use an installer. The main reasons for a registry setup, the Java browser plugin and the control panel, do not exist anymore. The reason left would be the ability to deinstall through the settings. But if you installed by copying the folder, you can deinstall by deleting the folder…

Comment: Glad to hear that's the case though as @Holger implies, mixing system-installed with manually installed could lead to problems . I know for certain that a lot of non-Windows problems are asked on this site over just that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Both would work - download installer or just transfer a jdk folder.
The advantage of using an installer is, that it most likely will setup the PATH variable for you, so that you can run it just with `java ...` or `javaw ...`.

With a transferred jdk (or better a downloaded zip file of a jdk e.g. from [https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/[version]](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/%5Bversion%5D)) you need to either explicitly state where to find the jdk (e.g. `c:\user\bla\Downloads\jdk\bin\javaw.exe ...`) or add the bin-path to the search path environment variable (PATH) your self.

I personally like the "download a zip file" version, as that makes it really simple to have different versions of java. As some stuff might not work with old versions but some other might not work with the most recent versions (at least not with some extra trouble).