# Why 'error loading jvm.dll' is shown when using a copied jdk?

Tags: java

I see a similar post in [install java or just copy jdk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027544/install-java-or-just-copy-jdk-file), but I encounter some error when I try to use copied **JDK** directly.

I installed **jdk11.0.8** on my Windows 10 machine and did a sanity check by executing '`java -version`' under the **\bin** directory of installed **jdk11.0.8**. This installed jdk works fine

Then I copied another **jdk11.0.7** from a shared folder (this is a working copy of someone else's jdk in his windows 10 machine) to my machine.

I tried to do a sanity check of this copied jdk by executing '`java -version`' under the \bin directory of this copied jdk. it gave error "Error: loading copied_jdk_path\bin\server.dll"

I see a difference here. The installed jdk works as expected, but the copied jdk (without installation )apparently does not work.

So how come in the original post I referenced at the top, many people replied that copied **jdk** file works just fine? Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you should try copying the jdk again, perhaps there was an error during the copy, perhaps you should try testing the same versions, perhaps you could then test if the files differ, perhaps you should expect them to differ if you are testing multiple different versions, perhaps you should explain why copying jdks is preferable to using the installer. In short, what problem are you trying to solve and how does this help you solve it?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch it's in company document to deal with situation that user does not have admin right so he can not run certain command against the JDK installed from company software centre (under c:\program files). and the solution is to get another copy of JDK in user folder when user has full access right.

Comment: more importantly to me is the question whether 'copy JDK works or not'. i've not done it before even though i used java quite some time now. some one (from oracle or open jdk) must know if this can be done as i imagine it can be a basic question for them.

Comment: you could try to install a "portable" version e.g. from [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net)  - there are other distributions available as well, that's just the first that came as a result of my search-fu...

Comment: user16320675 i am using oracle JDK, maybe that's why it has server.dll